# Setting up controller for nested and non-nested access

Tags: model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two models, Company and Contact.

I'd like to have the following routes (among others):

- `http://example.com/contacts` (lists
  all contacts)
- `http://example.com/company/1/contacts`
  (lists all contacts for company #1)

For sake of simplicity, the views will be identical except for the page title and breadcrumbs.

What is the best way to setup my `ContactsController`?  Are these two different actions?  Would my approach change if in the future I wanted to handle a 3rd type of route such as `http://example.com/salesregion/1/contacts`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with ruby on rails, but, using common MVC practice, this is how I would go about this solution:

Create a route that is something like this: **Contacts/{type}/{id}**

Where *type* can be (company, salesretion, etc.) and *id* would be the id of that given model. In theory then simply filter the query based on the given type.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I appreciate the response, but I'm really hoping someone with more rails experience can chime in.